# how to figure out when to use have verb + ed & just a verb

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions, causative-have

What should be the right answer for the blanks. and please explain why its correct.

Most decisions ______  several alternatives. For example,if you spend an hour studying for an economics exam, you have one fewer hour to pursue other activities.

Answers:

1.involve
2.have involved
3.were involving
4.include

Comment: Perhaps you have not learned the tenses yet? Your question is very open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Involve" is the correct choice. Statements that purport to be always true are typically phrased in the simple present.

> Roses have a lovely smell

implies neither that they stunk in the past nor that they will stink in the future.

"Involve" and "include" have overlapping fields of meaning, but the primary meaning of "involve" implies "be a participant" in some act or process whereas "include" may imply no more than to "be a member" and so has a less active implication. Thus, "involve" is better in this case because consideration of alternatives is a process rather than a state.

Answer (score -2):

In this context '
involve' is the right answer,as it logically agrees with its plural subject ---- 'Most decisions'.